Asset validation failed, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Invalid Executable. The executable hermes.framework/hermes' contains bitcode
if a build the app it is correct. archieve is also correct.  but when i upload app to Test Flight i get this error o MacOS 15 , Xcode 16 .
<IDEDistributionContext: 0x7f9ef32a6d50; archive = "<IDEArchive: 0x6000171f4620>", distributionMethod="(null)", team="(null)">
    <IDEDistributionContext: 0x7f9ef30a67d0; archive = "<IDEArchive: 0x6000171f4620>", distributionMethod="(null)", team="(null)">
    <IDEDistributionContext: 0x7f9ef0aff8d0; archive = "<IDEArchive: 0x6000171f4620>", distributionMethod="(null)", team="(null)">
</IDEDistributionContext: 0x7f9ef0a1a0f0>
2024-09-25 10:05:15 +0000 [MT] Upload for archive TrueCaller had issues:
(
    "<IDEDistributionIssue: severity(error), error(Error Domain=ContentDelivery Code=90482 \"Asset validation failed\" UserInfo={IDEDistributionIssueSeverity=3, NSLocalizedDescription=Asset validation failed, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Invalid Executable. The executable 'TrueCaller.app/Frameworks/hermes.framework/hermes' contains bitcode. (ID: 70394fde-4ed8-40ca-b6a8-2aabb46b397a)})>"


create a file in the ios folder with name `

handle_bitcode.sh`

use this commnad

touch handle_bitcode.sh

and then run this command

sudo chmod +x handle_bitcode.sh

and paste this script
#!/bin/bash

# Function to check if a binary contains bitcode
check_bitcode() {
  local binary_path=$1
  if otool -l "$binary_path" | grep -q __LLVM; then
    echo "$binary_path contains bitcode."
    echo "$binary_path" >> bitcode_frameworks.txt
  else
    echo "$binary_path does not contain bitcode."
  fi
}

# Function to strip bitcode from a binary
strip_bitcode() {
  local binary_path=$1
  local output_path="${binary_path}_stripped"
  xcrun bitcode_strip "$binary_path" -r -o "$output_path"
  echo "Stripped bitcode from $binary_path and saved to $output_path"
}

# Function to replace original binary with the stripped version
replace_framework() {
  local original_path=$1
  local stripped_path="${original_path}_stripped"

  if [ -f "$stripped_path" ]; then
    echo "Replacing $original_path with $stripped_path..."
    rm "$original_path"
    mv "$stripped_path" "$original_path"
    echo "Replaced $original_path successfully."
  else
    echo "Stripped binary $stripped_path not found. Skipping."
  fi
}

# Function to disable Bitcode in the Xcode project
disable_bitcode_in_project() {
  # Automatically detect the Xcode project file
  local xcodeproj_file=$(find . -name "*.xcodeproj" | head -n 1)
  if [ -z "$xcodeproj_file" ]; then
    echo "Xcode project not found. Exiting."
    exit 1
  fi
  local xcodeproj_name=$(basename "$xcodeproj_file" .xcodeproj)

  echo "Disabling Bitcode in Xcode project $xcodeproj_name..."
  /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :buildSettings:ENABLE_BITCODE NO" "$xcodeproj_file/project.pbxproj"

  # Clean and rebuild the Xcode project
  echo "Cleaning the build folder..."
  xcodebuild clean -workspace "$xcodeproj_name.xcworkspace" -scheme "$xcodeproj_name" -configuration Debug

  echo "Building the project..."
  xcodebuild -workspace "$xcodeproj_name.xcworkspace" -scheme "$xcodeproj_name" -configuration Debug

  echo "Process completed successfully!"
}

# Step 1: Check frameworks for Bitcode
echo "Checking frameworks for Bitcode..."

# Remove old bitcode_frameworks.txt if it exists
rm -f bitcode_frameworks.txt

# Check frameworks in Pods and the ios directory
if [ -d "Pods" ]; then
  echo "Checking frameworks in Pods..."
  find Pods -name '*.framework' -type d | while read -r framework; do
    binary_name=$(basename "$framework" .framework)
    binary_path="$framework/$binary_name"
    if [ -f "$binary_path" ]; then
      check_bitcode "$binary_path"
    fi
  done
fi

echo "Checking frameworks in the ios directory..."
find . -name '*.framework' -type d | while read -r framework; do
  binary_name=$(basename "$framework" .framework)
  binary_path="$framework/$binary_name"
  if [ -f "$binary_path" ]; then
    check_bitcode "$binary_path"
  fi
done

echo "Bitcode check completed. Frameworks containing bitcode are listed in bitcode_frameworks.txt."

# Step 2: Strip Bitcode from all frameworks that contain it
if [ -f bitcode_frameworks.txt ]; then
  echo "Stripping bitcode from frameworks..."
  while read -r binary_path; do
    strip_bitcode "$binary_path"
  done < bitcode_frameworks.txt
else
  echo "No frameworks found containing bitcode. Exiting."
  exit 1
fi

# Step 3: Replace original frameworks with stripped versions
echo "Replacing original frameworks with stripped versions..."
while read -r binary_path; do
  replace_framework "$binary_path"
done < bitcode_frameworks.txt

# Step 4: Disable Bitcode in the Xcode project and rebuild
disable_bitcode_in_project

in the termianl run this in ios folder

./handle_bitcode.sh


didnt work for me

@iamJohnvesly was that command successfull. i have tested it for react native and it worked

I was getting the same issue after upgraded to Xcode 16 and iOS 18.
You can solve this issue by  following this.

Open Podfile

Search for word post_install

If post_install not found then just directly paste the below code just before the last end keyword
 post_install do |installer|

 bitcode_strip_path = `xcrun --find bitcode_strip`.chop!
   def strip_bitcode_from_framework(bitcode_strip_path, framework_relative_path)
     framework_path = File.join(Dir.pwd, framework_relative_path)
     command = "#{bitcode_strip_path} #{framework_path} -r -o #{framework_path}"
     puts "Stripping bitcode: #{command}"
     system(command)
   end

   framework_paths = [
     "Pods/LogRocket/LogRocket.xcframework/ios-arm64/LogRocket.framework/LogRocket",
     "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/macosx/hermes.framework/hermes",
     "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/macosx/hermes.framework/Versions/Current/hermes",
     "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/universal/hermes.xcframework/ios-arm64/hermes.framework/hermes",
     "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/universal/hermes.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-maccatalyst/hermes.framework/hermes"
   ]

   framework_paths.each do |framework_relative_path|
     strip_bitcode_from_framework(bitcode_strip_path, framework_relative_path)
   end


In case you have already post_install has been used then copy and past the below script inside that.
   bitcode_strip_path = `xcrun --find bitcode_strip`.chop!
   def strip_bitcode_from_framework(bitcode_strip_path, framework_relative_path)
     framework_path = File.join(Dir.pwd, framework_relative_path)
     command = "#{bitcode_strip_path} #{framework_path} -r -o #{framework_path}"
     puts "Stripping bitcode: #{command}"
     system(command)
   end

   framework_paths = [
     "Pods/LogRocket/LogRocket.xcframework/ios-arm64/LogRocket.framework/LogRocket",
     "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/macosx/hermes.framework/hermes",
     "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/macosx/hermes.framework/Versions/Current/hermes",
     "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/universal/hermes.xcframework/ios-arm64/hermes.framework/hermes",
     "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/universal/hermes.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-maccatalyst/hermes.framework/hermes"
   ]

   framework_paths.each do |framework_relative_path|
     strip_bitcode_from_framework(bitcode_strip_path, framework_relative_path)
   end


Do pod install

Do archive again and try upload



Is there any risk stripping all this bitcode? Will my app work correctly?

based off of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73219854/8183900 it seems like the answer to my comment is no

for anyone that gets stuck, this may sound silly, but running pod install is essential for this to work

thanks, this worked for me, I added the code to the end of  "post_install do |installer|"

just to be clear. We don't have to remove what it was inside pod_install section. The code suggested here should be pasted after our current code if exists.


if you are using RN version below 0.72 you might face error like this
change your podfile to this
below is the full code of podfile
ignore comments

require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '13.0'
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false

target 'myApp' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )
  
  pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'
  pod 'RNCPicker', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-picker/picker'
  pod 'RNReanimated', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-reanimated'

  target 'myAppTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  use_flipper!()

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)

    bitcode_strip_path = `xcrun --find bitcode_strip`.chomp
    unless bitcode_strip_path.empty?
      def strip_bitcode_from_framework(bitcode_strip_path, framework_relative_path)
        framework_path = File.join(Dir.pwd, framework_relative_path)
        if File.exist?(framework_path)
          command = "#{bitcode_strip_path} #{framework_path} -r -o #{framework_path}"
          puts "Stripping bitcode: #{command}"
          system(command)
        else
          puts "Framework not found at path: #{framework_path}, skipping bitcode strip."
        end
      end

      framework_paths = [
        "Pods/LogRocket/LogRocket.xcframework/ios-arm64/LogRocket.framework/LogRocket",
        "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/macosx/hermes.framework/hermes",
        "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/macosx/hermes.framework/Versions/Current/hermes",
        "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/universal/hermes.xcframework/ios-arm64/hermes.framework/hermes",
        "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/universal/hermes.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-maccatalyst/hermes.framework/hermes"
      ]

      framework_paths.each do |framework_relative_path|
        strip_bitcode_from_framework(bitcode_strip_path, framework_relative_path)
      end
    else
      puts "bitcode_strip tool not found, skipping bitcode stripping."
    end
  end
end


now run

pod install

