I have increased react-native version of my app to 0.75.3 it's working fine on android but for ios it is giving error related to hermes engine
Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-bnqohelonpfvjpescjpbsmsquwly/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/hermes-engine.build/Script-46EB2E0005D340.sh: line 2: /scripts/xcode/with-environment.sh: No such file or directory
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code.
I tried removing pod, clearing cache and derived data as well.
but it is not working for ios.

Have you tried cd ios && pod install && cd ..

@Diksha Try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79022303/asset-validation-failed-nslocalizedrecoverysuggestion-invalid-executable-the-e/79022687#79022687

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
